# Pasaje de tabla a Excel usando SheetJS cambia el valor de las fechas

Tags: javascript, excel, date, sheetjs

estoy intentando pasar una tabla de JS a Excel con un boton de exportar tabla a excel, pero las fechas por ej: "03/01/2024" quedan como 229/02/2024  23:59:09", termine haciendo que solo se pasaran los mes y año... pero necesito que se pase la fecha completa.
Alguna sugerencia? Dejo el codigo sin el cambio de formato a solo dia y año:

```
function exportarTablaAExcel(tableID, filename = '') {

    const tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);

    // Eliminar el paginado y mostrar todos los elementos
    const listElement = tableSelect.querySelector('tbody');
    const children = listElement.children;
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        children[i].style.display = 'table-row';
    }

    // Crear un libro de trabajo (workbook) con una hoja (worksheet)
    const wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(tableSelect, { sheet: 'SheetJS' });

    // Convertir el libro de trabajo a un objeto binario (binary)
    const wbout = XLSX.write(wb, { type: 'binary', bookType: 'xlsx' });

    // Crear un arreglo de bytes para el archivo Excel
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(wbout.length);
    const view = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0; i < wbout.length; i++) {
        view[i] = wbout.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
    }

    // Crear un Blob a partir del arreglo de bytes
    const blob = new Blob([buf], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });

    // Crear un enlace para descargar el archivo
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloadLink.download = filename ? filename + '.xlsx' : `Descarga-Excel-${Fecha()}.xlsx`;

    // Simular el clic en el enlace para descargar el archivo
    downloadLink.click();

    // Revocar el objeto URL creado
    URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadLink.href);

    //Reiniciar tabla
    crearTabla(mostrarConOrden(datos.mostrar(),"Descendente"),"suministrosTBody","suministrosTHead");
    //Aviso de fechas invertidas en documento excel
    enviarMensaje("info", "Listo!", `Ir a carpeta de descargas para acceder al archivo .XLSX .`);

}
```

Comment: Hola Federico, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomido realizar el [tour] para que aprendas como funciona la plataforma y de paso ganar otra medalla. ¿Podrías agregar un [mcve]?